# firebase custom domain name dynamic links not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase hosting. I have index.html file.

It's opening via Both Firebase URL and Custom Domain.

If anyone tries open `example.com` it should open index.html

But if anyone try to open `example.com/?link=https://google.com` it should dynamically open the URL in link parameter.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Even if the link parameter is present. It still opens the `index.html` file.

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
"appAssociation": "AUTO",
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/?link**",
    "dynamicLinks": true
  },
  {
    "source": "!/?link**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the rewrite rule for index.html

```
{
  "source": "!/?link**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
}
```

and remove `?` on the `dynamicLinks` rewrite rule source. It should look like this.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/link**",
      "dynamicLinks": true
    }]
  }
}
```

Deploy the changes again and this should set `https://example.com/link` as your Dynamic Link domain. You can test if the FDL domain functional by manually adding FDL parameters on the domain.

i.e. https://example.com/link?link=https://google.com

Comment: I removed this, Still it's not redirecting the dynamic links.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I missed the `?` set on the `dynamicLinks` source. That should also be removed.

Comment: Thank Omatt. How many Redirection can I make like this? Is it unlimited or what?

Comment: Same for me, redirection still does not work in 2023. Documentation on this is horrible.